# Why is a MarionetteJS module gets undefined jQuery?

Tags: marionette

I have the following code:

app.js

```
var AgencyUI = new Marionette.Application();

AgencyUI.addRegions({
    gridRegion: "#gridRegion"
});

AgencyUI.on("initialize:after", function() {
    AgencyUI.trigger("grid:loadGrid");
});
```

grid_app.js

```
AgencyUI.module('GridApp', function(GridApp, AgencyUI, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    var API = {
        loadGrid: function(dateRange) {
            GridApp.Show.Controller.loadGrid(dateRange);
        }
    };

    AgencyUI.on("grid:loadGrid", function(dateRange) {
        API.loadGrid(dateRange);
    });
});
```

show_controller.js

```
AgencyUI.module('GridApp.Show', function(Show, AgencyUI, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Show.Controller = {
        loadGrid: function(dateRange) {
            // undefined
            console.log($);
        }
    };  
});
```

Why is jQuery ($) undefined?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious guess: jQuery simply hasn't loaded yet. Perhaps the script references are added in the wrong order or this particular code is executed before jQuery has been loaded.